# IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: roomer_room.id in django test case

Tags: python, django

I have a test case where I want to check the hungarian algorithm for assigning rooms by taking data from the database. So, I create a few objects in the `setUp` method to populate some data. However, upon executing the tests, they fail (essentially, the `setUp` fails) with following stack trace:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_hungarian_on_users (allocation.tests.TestHungarian)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/allocation/tests.py", line 68, in setUp
    code='MA-302'
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/roomer/models.py", line 297, in save
    super(Room, self).save(kwargs)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 820, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 859, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/parthshukla/roomer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: roomer_room.id

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The error seems to originate out of integrity constraints for roomer_room.id (django generated UUID) which signals that there are existing rooms with that ID. However, `Room.objects.all()` right before line 68 (first call to `Room.objects.create()`) where the error stems from, returns an empty array. So, there are no other objects in the Room table which makes sense since the django tests create a new database upon spawning the test case and destroy it upon teardown. Here's the test case for reference.

```
class TestHungarian(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.basic_cost_matrix = [[82, 83, 69, 92], [77, 37, 49, 92], [11, 69, 5, 86], [8, 9, 98, 23]]
        self.basic_hungarian_result = [69, 37, 11, 23]
        # Basically Leo
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            username='a',
            seniority=2,
            year=17,
            major='Computer Science',
            country='Germany',
            old_college='NM',
            college='ME',
        )

        # Basically Sid
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            username='b',
            seniority=3,
            year=16,
            major='Computer Science',
            country='India',
            old_college='ME',
            college='ME',
        )

        # Basically a mover
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            username='c',
            seniority=1,
            year=18,
            major='Physics',
            country='Albania',
            old_college='NM',
            college='ME',
        )

        # Basically a Nordie freshie
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            username='d',
            seniority=1,
            year=18,
            major='Chemistry',
            country='Albania',
            old_college='NM',
            college='NM',
        )

        user_a = UserProfile.objects.get(username='a')
        user_b = UserProfile.objects.get(username='b')
        user_c = UserProfile.objects.get(username='c')
        user_d = UserProfile.objects.get(username='d')
        # user_a.send_roommate_request(user_b)
        # user_b.inbox.first().accept()

        Room.objects.create(
            college='ME',
            floor=3,
            block='A',
            code='MA-302'
        )
        Room.objects.create(
            college='ME',
            floor=2,
            block='A',
            code='MA-203'
        )
        Room.objects.create(
            college='ME',
            floor=3,
            block='C',
            code='MC-104'
        )
        Room.objects.create(
            college='NM',
            floor=3,
            block='B',
            code='NB-351'
        )
        Room.objects.create(
            college='NM',
            floor=3,
            block='B',
            code='NA-350'
        )

        room_a = Room.objects.get(code='MA-302')
        room_b = Room.objects.get(code='MA-203')
        room_c = Room.objects.get(code='NB-351')
        room_d = Room.objects.get(code='MC-104')
        room_e = Room.objects.get(code='NA-350')
        # room_a.associated.add(room_b)

        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=1,
            user=user_a,
            room=room_b
        )
        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=2,
            user=user_a,
            room=room_d
        )
        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=1,
            user=user_b,
            room=room_a
        )
        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=2,
            user=user_b,
            room=room_d
        )
        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=1,
            user=user_c,
            room=room_d
        )
        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=2,
            user=user_c,
            room=room_a
        )
        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=1,
            user=user_d,
            room=room_c
        )
        UserPreference.objects.create(
            preference_level=2,
            user=user_d,
            room=room_e
        )

        self.pref_a = UserPreference.objects.get(user=user_a, preference_level=1)
        self.pref_b = UserPreference.objects.get(user=user_b, preference_level=1)
        self.pref_c = UserPreference.objects.get(user=user_c, preference_level=1)
        self.pref_d = UserPreference.objects.get(user=user_d, preference_level=1)

    def test_basic_hungarian(self):
        result = get_cost_matrix(self.basic_cost_matrix)
        self.assertEqual(result, self.basic_hungarian_result)

    def test_hungarian_on_users(self):
        allocations = get_hungarian()
        self.assertEqual(get_dict_from_key_in_list("user", "sshukla", allocations)["preference"], self.pref_b.preference_level)
```

Comment: What do you think `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: roomer_room.id` might mean?

Comment: @JohnMee Well, usually it's supposed to refer to the fact that the object exists in the database since roomer_room.id (django generated UUID) is already on some table in the db. However, django tests create and destroy the database upon setUp and teardown. So, this doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: The error message tells us that there are two roomer_room's trying to use the same id.  Go looking for that.  Perhaps near line 68.

Comment: @JohnMee Line 68 is the first call to Room.objects.create in the setUp method. There are no duplicates which is what makes the whole error a lot confusing. :/

Comment: How do you know there are no duplicates?

Comment: @JohnMee because I presume that is the first time a Room object is being added to the Room table since it's a fresh database that gets spun up every time the test is run. Also, `Room.objects.all()` returns an empty array.

Comment: Between a hard error and a presumption, I'd take a closer look at the presumption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111686/discussion-between-siddharth-shukla-and-john-mee).

Comment: are you seeing this for the very first test or subsequent ones?

Comment: For all the tests in the test case. I found out the reason for failure. The `Room.objects.create()` did not create a primary key. After overriding id with my own uuid based implementation, the errors go away.

Comment: That's a bit strange, I recall seeing a bug report a while back about UUID not working but that was more than an year ago. In the end I also ended up using my own id generating mechanism. My question about whether this occured  in the first test or on subsequent tests was because I wondered if you had an sql execption anywhere else in your code and your test was misbehaving after that because it was a TestCase instead of TransactionTestCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was that the `Room.objects.create()` did not create a primary key. Creating a primary key manually fixes the problem.